# FadeIn and FadeOut different backgrounds into each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem with my example below is that the last background doesn't show for 6 seconds as planned in the `setInterval` function but fades instantly into the first one.

Of course I want it to behave the same as the rest of them.
I don't think it changes anything but my real example has images for backgrounds instead of colors, just changed it to be a bit easier for this example.

Thank you for your help and time in advance!

```js
var screen = 0,
  speed = 1000;

window.setInterval(function() {
  $(".background-" + ((screen % 4) + 1)).fadeOut(speed,
    function() {
      $(".background-" + (((screen + 1) % 4) + 1)).fadeIn(speed);
    });
  screen += 1
}, 6000);
```

```css
.background-1 {
  background: red;
  z-index: 6;
  position: absolute;
}

.background-2 {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
}

.background-3 {
  background: green;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
}

.background-4 {
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="background background-1">

  </div>
  <div class="background background-2">

  </div>
  <div class="background background-3">

  </div>
  <div class="background background-4">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var screen = 0,
    speed = 1000;

    window.setInterval(function() {
       $(".background-" + ((screen % 4) + 1)).fadeOut(speed, 
       function() {
           $(".background-" + (((screen + 1) % 4) + 1)).fadeIn(speed);
             screen+=1
       });
    },6000);
```

```css
.background-1 {
       background: red;
       z-index: 6;
       position: absolute;
    }
   .background-2 {
       background: blue;
       z-index: 5;
       position: absolute;
   }
   .background-3 {
       background: green;
       z-index: 4;
       position: absolute;
   }
   .background-4 {
       background: yellow;
       z-index: 3;
       position: absolute;
   }
   .wrapper{
   width:400px;
   }
   .background {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
                <div class="background background-1">

                </div>
                <div class="background background-2">

                </div>
                <div class="background background-3">

                </div>
                <div class="background background-4">

                </div>
            </div>
```

Set the variable `screen` increment in the callback function of fadeout.

Comment: Thank you! It works, however another problem occurs. After the first loop, the each background element fades out into an empty background and then fades in into another background element.

Comment: @laidback1 Adjust the speed time according to your need

Comment: I think its more of a problem with the logic i applied than with the speed time variable since after the 4th background it fades into an unexisting background number.

Comment: @laidback1 Yes. The speed is 1000, so fadein+fadeout takes 2000,There are 4 elements too. Create logic based on this.

Comment: Ok, sorry to bother you a bit more. So after looking into the devtools I figured out (smart me! ;) ) that the problem here is that after the first loop, all of the .background elements are set to display:none because of the fadeOut hence why it appears as if the second loop faded into an empty background. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var speed = 1000;
        var counter = 0
        var divlist = $('.background-1, .background-2, .background-3,.background-4');

        function showDiv() {
            divlist.fadeOut(speed)
                .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; })
                .fadeIn(speed);

            counter++;
        };

        showDiv();

        setInterval(function () {
            showDiv();
        }, 6000);
    });
</script>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="background background-1">
        111111111111111111
    </div>
    <div class="background background-2">
        22222222222222222222
    </div>
    <div class="background background-3">
        33333333333333333333333333
    </div>
    <div class="background background-4">
        4444444444444444444444444
    </div>
</div>
```